# Can't install pgadmin4 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I'm following the steps outlined online: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/. My original error said "Package pgadmin4 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate."

I did some digging and step 2 is not downloading the repo config file to /etc/apt/sources.list.d.

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'`

Are there any ways around this? Are there any alternatives to download the repo config file?
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Il seems that Ubuntu 21.10 impish is not yet supported by the Package repository of pgadmin

But it also seems that the version for the previous Ubuntu version, 21.04 hirsute, works on 21.10 impish

To correct, edit the file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list
```

and change impish by hirsute:

```
deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/**hirsute** pgadmin4 main
```

Answer (score -1):

E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/**hirsute** pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

But, I just solved my problem by following the directions (exactly) at https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/